# Laravel - retrieve all user with their project from two tables using Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables

1- projects
2- clients

I need to get the names from the client table and the project name from the projects table

my Projects class has

```
public function projectClient()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('User');
    }
```

and my User class has

```
    class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface
{

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'client';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

    public function project()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Projects', 'id');
    }

}
```

and in my clients controller

```
$clients = User::with('project')->get();
        //dd($clients);
        return View::make('admin.manageClients.viewClients', compact('clients'));
```

now in the view I try this

```
@foreach($clients as $clt)
{{ $clt->first_name }} //work fine
{{ $clt->pro_title }} //didn't show the project title
@endforeach
```

how can I show this project title here?

**Update**

as @Mahfuzul Alam and @WebKenth suggest I did it like this

`{{ $clt->project->pro_title }}`

but something still wrong there

in my database I got two user and the the `project_id` = 1
but in my `view` the first user `project_id` = 1 and the second `project_id` = 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering, `pro_title` as your project title column try `{{ $clt->project->pro_title }}`. If it don't work, they please paste code of your `User` class and let us take a look at that.

Comment: now I can't understand why I getting wrong results here I should see client_1 with pro_1 and client_2 with pro_1 but I got client_1 with pro_1 and client_2 with pro_2 why I getting pro_2 with client_2 it should be pro_1 any help pls

Comment: Seems that I was not in mode it was the `User` class it was `return $this->belongsTo('Projects', 'id');` and it should be `return $this->belongsTo('Projects', 'project_id');` anyway thx for all

Answer (score 1):

consider renaming the projectClient relationship to `client()`

this way you can call `$project->client` and receive the client object from the project.

As for your problem, you are not referencing the `Project` object on the client, you have the relationship so a simple call to `$clt->projects`will return the `Project` object on each $clt.

Comment: now I changed the `projectClient` relationship to `client()` but I can't understand why I getting wrong results here I should see `client_1` with `pro_1` and `client_2` with `pro_1` but I got `client_1` with `pro_1` and `client_2` with `pro_2` why I getting `pro_2` with `client_2` it should be `pro_1`